# I am facing a problem of fetching data (React, useEffect)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I am trying to fetch data from the URL given below, sometimes I am getting but most of the time not in the console. I don't know about the problem I have tried with async-await but the result was the same.

https://quiet-forest-82433.herokuapp.com/myorders/?email=liza@liza.com

My code is:

```
const {user} = useAuth();
const [totalCart, setTotalCart] = useState({})

useEffect(() => {
    const url = `https://quiet-forest-82433.herokuapp.com/myorders/?email=${user?.email}`
    fetch(url)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data =>  console.log(data))
}, []);
```

Comment: When the code fails, what do your browser's debugging tools tell you?  Are there any errors at all on the browser's development console?  In the network tab of those tools, is the AJAX request made?  What is the server's response?  There's nothing inherently wrong with the code shown, so what specifically happens?

Comment: Should you perhaps add the `user?.email` in the `useEffect` dependency list ?

Comment: I am not getting any error in the console, I am using a chrome browser. I was showing an empty array for console.log and I have got only one time that is given 2 elements in the array.

Comment: @Hosen: So when it "doesn't work" that means it's successfully logging an empty array to the console?  If that's the case then the server successfully returned an empty array.  Again, examine the network tab in the browser's debugging tools.  Observe the AJAX request being made.  Is it what you expect?  If you're sending the expected request to the server and the server returns an empty array then the code is working fine, you'd need to check with the server.

Comment: @David, you for your cooperation it didn't have any dependency but now I have added a dependency of email, it's working fine.

Comment: @Gabriele Petrioli thank you, no it wasn't but now I  have added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

useEffect should have a dependency on `user`.
And don't call fetch until you have a valid user email. Currently, you're code will ask for email=undefined until the user populates, but the useEffect() will not fire again because there is no dependency on user.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (!user || !user.email) return

    const url = `https://quiet-forest-82433.herokuapp.com/myorders/?email=${user?.email}`
    fetch(url)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data =>  console.log(data))
}, [user]);
```